# How to control a radio button text margins

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

Using Visual c# Express edition

I have the following result

[image: existing form]

But obviously i'd rather increase the radio button height and fit all the text in a shorter space.
I tried increasing the height in the radio button properties, but it would set me back to 17.
Edit: \n on the text doesn't work either.

Edit 2: what i want is to give the text a square form, so that it doesn't extend beyond the "categoria de terreno" groupbox. I want the whole text to be visible inside the groupbox.

Comment: Its not clear what you would like to accomplish yet. Consider adding more details about what you *want* to happen and why your current solution isn't sufficient.

Comment: I wanna give the text a square shaped form, so that it fits the groupbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `AutoSize` property to `false` in the properties window for each of the radio buttons. Then you can resize the radio button to fit within the width of the group box and the text will wrap automatically. You can then use `CheckAlign` and `TextAlign` to adjust the alignment of the radio circle and the text.

Comment: @ng80092b if it works/helps, you should acknowledge that by clicking the checkmark

Comment: Is it checked now? I tried too, but it told me i should wait 5 minutes

Comment: Yes, it's checked. Thanks!